# android alarm broadcast not received when app crashed

Tags: android, repeatingalarm

I have set a repetitive alarm for every 3 minutes. I received all the broadcast until my app crashed. After that i did not receive any broadcast. Can any one please tell why this happned. Thank you

Comment: app crash -> process killed -> alarm cancelled

Comment: how can i reset the alarm. I am using shared preferences to store if the alarm is set or not.Hence it will be only set once.

Comment: Re-set it when the app is restarted

Comment: the alarm is set in splash activity,how can i differ if the activity is called in normal time  or when the app is crashed, and when will i change the shared preference value to alarm not set

Comment: Just fix the crash, then you won't have to worry about this